# Running java program through cmd ERROR: no main method found

Tags: java, batch-file

I am trying to run a bat file to easily run my program. The Batch file is in the folder project folder, along side the bin folder.
I have many classes in many different packages. But the main method is in my Game.class which is located in:
 bin\xx\xx\xxxx\xxx\xxxxxx\cards\game\Game.class

So I have set two bat files and tried them both:
1.

```
java -cp bin\xx\xx\xxxx\xxx\xxxxxx\cards\game Game
```

2.

```
java -cp bin.xx.xx.xxxx.xxx.xxxxxx.cards.game Game
```

Both times I get this error:

**Could not find or load main class Game**

Comment: I think that you must add a ./ like: java -cp ./ bin\xx\xx\xxxx\xxx\xxxxxx\cards\game Game

Comment: 1st one is correct approach. Do you have static main in `Game` class?

Comment: @JFPicard Thank you for the reply. Same error as before except the error now prints "..and load class bin.xx.xx.xxxx.xxx.xxxxxx.cards.game"

Comment: @Dilip 100% I have a static main in my Game class

Comment: is `bin.xx.xx....` package name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes more sense:

```
java -cp /path/to/"class-root"/ full.qualified.name.of.Game
```

...where "/path/to/class-root/" is probably "bin" in your case, and relates to "default package" (no package). From there on the path should be consistent with the package(s) of your class(es)

Comment: This is the closest I've gotten so far. But i have other folders and files in the project folder (alongside bin) that need to be used and its not using these...... It works perfectly in the eclipse command IDE.

Comment: I moved the bat file onto the same drive, and it seems to work perfectly now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, -cp should match(contain) "eclipse output directory", I am glad being helpful, Thanks for "accept".